# Inverse Matrix of a Special Matrix for Optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

For some portfolio optimization problems, it finally comes to an inverse matrix of a special matrix
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
A & \mathbf{1} \\
\mathbf{1}' & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $A$ is a symmetric matrix and $\mathbf{1}=(1,\cdots,1)'\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Can anyone help to find the inverse matrix of matrix $B$?

Thanks a lot!

---

Below is the background of the above problem:

Assume $\omega$ is the weight vector of the portfolio, $\mu$ is the return vector and $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix. The constraint is $\sum\omega=1$. For different optimization problems, we will have different targets:

1. For the optimization problem of minimum variance:
   $$\min_\omega\omega'\Sigma\omega$$
   applying the Lagrange multiplier, we have the matrix equation
   $$\begin{bmatrix}
   2\Sigma & \mathbf{1} \\
   \mathbf{1}' & 0
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   \omega \\
   \lambda
   \end{bmatrix}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
   \mathbf{0} \\
   1
   \end{bmatrix}$$
2. For the optimization problem of mean-variance optimization:
   $$\max_\omega\omega'\mu-\frac{1}{2}\delta\omega'\Sigma\omega$$
   applying the Lagrange multiplier, we have the matrix equation
   $$\begin{bmatrix}
   -\delta\Sigma & \mathbf{1} \\
   \mathbf{1}' & 0
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   \omega \\
   \lambda
   \end{bmatrix}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
   -\mu \\
   1
   \end{bmatrix}$$

Anyway, it comes to the problem of inverse matrix of
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
A & \mathbf{1} \\
\mathbf{1}' & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you for providing the background. You should try to see if your problem falls under the Woodbury matrix identity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Properties) of $A$ to get the formula
$$
B^{-1} = \pmatrix{A^{-1} + A^{-1}\mathbf 1 (B/A)^{-1}\mathbf 1' A^{-1} & -A^{-1}\mathbf 1(B/A)^{-1}\\
-(B/A)^{-1}\mathbf 1' A^{-1} & (B/A)^{-1}},
$$
where
$$
B/A = 0 - \mathbf 1' A^{-1} \mathbf 1 = -\mathbf 1' A^{-1} \mathbf 1 \in \Bbb R.
$$
We can rewrite the above in the following arguably simpler form:
$$
B^{-1} = \pmatrix{A^{-1} & 0\\0 & 0} + \frac 1{\mathbf 1' A^{-1} \mathbf 1}\pmatrix{\mathbf{vv}' & - \mathbf v\\ -\mathbf v' & 1}
\\ = 
\pmatrix{A^{-1} & 0\\0 & 0} + \frac 1{\mathbf 1' A^{-1} \mathbf 1}
\pmatrix{-\mathbf v\\ 1} \pmatrix{-\mathbf v \\ 1}',
$$
where $\mathbf v = A^{-1} \mathbf 1$.

Comment: +1 but you need to fix a sign error $\pmatrix{{\bf v}\\{\tt1}}\to\pmatrix{{\bf v}\\-{\tt1}}$

Comment: @greg Good catch

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kindly help!